# WinRT C# Metro Play MediaElement Asynchronous

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, mediaelement, winrt-async

Im trying to build Win8 metro style application. Im trying to play remote video which is on web in media element.

```
      MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
        Uri url = new Uri("some url on web");
        media.Source = url;
        media.Play();
```

The first streaming takes time. It takes time to video to start play, in this meantime application is locked. I want to do that playing ascnhronously. How can i achive this.

Comment: Look up the notion of a promise http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help but is there C# equvalient of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some search, i find out that with dispatcher element, i can do my work asynchronously. Here is the sample:

```
await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
            MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
            Uri url = new Uri("some url on web");
            media.Source = url;
            media.Play();
         }

        );
```

You have to mark the calling function as async in order this code block to work.